# Application of knot theory

Tags: knot-theory

I am looking for applications of knot theory as many as possible.
I heard from professor "Chromosome of mad cow disease is knotted, but ordinary one is no knotted"
Because of enlarging my motivation, I would like to know applications as many as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Application to modeling cancer: https://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/economic-sciences/laureates/2005/aumann-bio.html

Excerpt: 'My grandson Yakov Rosen, who is in the second year of medical school, is on the line. "Grandpa," he says, "can I pick your brain? We are studying knots. I don't understand the material, and think that our lecturer does not understand it either. For example, what, exactly, are ‘linking numbers'?" "Why are you studying knots?" I ask. "What do knots have to do with medicine?" "Well," says Yakov, "sometimes the DNA in a cell gets knotted up. Depending on the characteristics of the knot, this may lead to cancer. So, we have to understand knots."'

Comment: Thank you very much for the concrete example. I want know more abou how knotted condition make the cell cancer. Please show me article if possible.